# When uninstalling apps installed via Windows Store, how do I make sure none of its leftover files or folders remain?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, windows-store, windows-store-app

Back on Windows 7, I could use software such as Revo Uninstaller which will scan my system for leftover files and folders that may be related to the uninstalled program. On Windows 10 modern apps, how do I do this?

Comment: you don't need such tools for store apps

Comment: @magicandre1981 Why not?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 10 apps I don't think you need them, but there is software that scan your drive for left overs. E.g., you can use tools as IOBit Uninstaller or Revo Uninstaller (those are the most well-known) and there are many others.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser! Your answer seems correct, but it seems a bit like ad. This will edit your answer for you. Please read and use the rules for writing answers correctly.

Comment: Hi, I used Revo Uninstaller but the apps from Windows Store don't show up there.

Answer (score 0):

CCCleaner is a tool that seems to be able to uninstall Windows Store apps. Check the screenshot where I could remove Photos and Wallet if I wanted to. Hope that helps. Its available here on [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ccleaner)

[image]